# How to use JavaScript to display HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, so basically I am using a JavaScript script to detect whether ad blocker is enabled on the visitor's browser or not. I successfully got it to popup an alert box, but that was just a basic test. Now, I'd like to replace the ad slot with an image the size of the ad that says my message about how it would be nice if they could allow ads. How would I achieve this using JavaScript?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
        function TestPage() {
if ($('.myTopAd').height() == 0)
    alert('Please disable your adblocker!');
}

$(TestPage);
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I generally don't like downvoting new user questions, but if you cannot figure out how to do what you ask from the many questions already answered here, I don't think I can help you.

Comment: Why would anyone using an ad-blocker agree to disable their ad-blocking in response to the web-site?

Comment: @JayC, very nice of you to down vote a beginner programmer.

Comment: @DavidThomas lots of forum sites do it.

Comment: I didn't ask if it was a popular tactic, I was simply curious as to how effective you thought it might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `if`, you can do something like this:

```
$('.myTopAd').prepend($('<img>',{id:'ID-OF-IMG',src:'YOUR-IMAGE.jpg'}));
```

Or

```
$(".myTopAd").prepend("<img id='ID-OF-IMG' src='YOUR-IMAGE.jpg'/>");
```

In src, put the path of your image.

This can be done on several ways, these are just some of them.

[Prepend jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeLink()
{
if ($('.myTopAd').height() == 0){
document.getElementById('.myTopAd').src= "asd.png";
document.getElementById('.myTopAd').alt= "TEXT@";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<img id="myTopAd" src="sss.png" alt="TEXT"</a>
<input type="button" onclick="changeLink()" value="Change link">

</body>
</html>
```

try this.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to help the OP better understand what you are trying to convey with your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can set a **background-image** to the ads parent element

```
function TestPage() {
  if ($('.myTopAd').height() == 0){
    $('.myTopAd-parent').css({background: "url(please.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%", backgorundSize: "cover"});
  }
}

$(function(){ // DOM is now ready
   TestPage(); 
});
```

Or do the similar appending an image:

```
$('.myTopAd-parent').append("<img src='please.jpg'>");
```